# curl file only contains 0 not html

Tags: html, c, curl

I try to get some HTML code from google.de, this works fine.
Also my printf prints the code into the console like it should, but the file does only contains a "0" and not the "hmtl code".

```
int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("/Users/xxx/Desktop/html.txt","a+");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=wetter+paderborn&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=eNWRUr7xGtPY4QS5rYD4Cw#q=wetter+paderborn&rls…");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        printf("%u",res);
        fprintf(file,"%u",res);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're only writing the return code from `curl_easy_perform` to file. I think you need to also call [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) for option `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` if you want to save any returned data.

Comment: @simonc i don't get it does you maybe have a example?